# Merge two objects and ignore unique keys

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two objects `original` and `custom`. I want to merge `custom` to `original`, but ignore the keys from `original` that are not found in `custom` object. For example:

```
var original = {

    coupon: {
            coupon: "Coupon",
            couponTypes: {
                single: "Single",
            }
        },

    language: {
            Language: "Language",
            chooseLanguage: "Choose your language",
            }

        }


 var custom = {

    coupon: {
        coupon: "Coupon Details",
        couponTypes: {
            single: "Single Coupon",
        }
    }   
}
```

The expected result should be like this:

```
 var result = {

     coupon: {
            coupon: "Coupon",
            couponTypes: {
                single: "Single",
            }
        }   
    }
```

It should replace only the values for those keys which exists in custom object and ignore the other.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token default`.

Comment: the expected result doesn't look to be "replaced". It's just a filtered value

Comment: Your "expected result" isn't really expected. Can you clarify the rule ?

Comment: My apologies for being rude, but I do not see any attempt. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question shows no sign of effort.

Comment: I don't think question should be closed as such. Seems like an interesting question.

Comment: What I'm currently using  `JSON.stringify(Object.assign({}, original, custom)` to merge both objects to one and it works. The only thing I need now is just ignore the keys from original object that don't exist in custom object.

Comment: @NevinMadhukarK It might be interesting, but still showing effort is mandatory. Let OP share his effort. This will enable us to see where he has stuck and is the approach correct. This way we can help OP with more than solution of this problem. Also it will prove that OP has tried something and not using SO to get work done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to this kind of problem is recursive:

```js
var def={coupon:{coupon:"Coupon",couponTypes:{single:"Single"}},language:{Language:"Language",chooseLanguage:"Choose your language"}},
    custom={coupon:{coupon:"Coupon Details",couponTypes:{single:"Single Coupon"}}};

function merge(a, b) {
  var c = {};
  for (var k in a) {
    if (k in b) c[k] = typeof b[k] === "object" ? merge(a[k], b[k]) : b[k];
  }
  return c;
}

console.log(merge(custom, def));
```

Comment: this differs from the OP's expected result

Comment: I have just minified objects so that emphasis is on your logic. If not required, please revert it. :-)